# 'pyramid-debugtoolbar' distribution was not found and is required

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pyramid, pyramid-debug-toolbar

I'm trying to debug my pyramid application via eclipse. I've followed the instructions in [this link](http://www.devsniper.com/pyramid-framework-settings-in-eclipse-aptana-studio/).

When I try to run my app, I get the following error:

```
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pyramid-debugtoolbar' distribution was not found and is required by..
```

I've **un-commented** the line in **development.ini** `pyramid.includes = pyramid_debugtoolbar`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 9):

You most forgot to run:

```
python setup.py develop
```

For your application so it didn't pull all the required dependancies.

```
pip install -e .
```

willl also work.